# how to read xml from request in node js which consumes xml

Tags: xml, node.js, post

I'm exposing a post method in node as

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    var postData='';
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

    if(request.method==="POST"){
        request.setEncoding("utf8");
        console.log('in post');
        request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
            postData += postDataChunk;
            console.log("Receiving POST data chunk '"+postDataChunk + "'.");
        });
        request.addListener("end", function() {
           console.log("Received POST data ");
           console.log(postData);
        });    
    }
}
```

I expect the console log to be xml string .

```
<ContainerItem>
          <Id>Id</Id>
          <Name>Name</Name>
          <Description>Description</Description>
          <Type>Type</Type>
  </ContainerItem>
```

But it gives me output as :

```
text=%3CContainerItem%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CId%3EId%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CName%3EName%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CDescription%3EDescription%3C%2FDescription%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CType%3EType%3C%2FType%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FContainerItem%3E
```

How can i get this as XML string ? so that i can parse it using xml2js library .

Answer (score 0):

The data is received in querystring format, and is URL encoded when you receive it, so you need to decode it. You can use the native [query string](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module for this purpose:

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var str = 'text=%3CContainerItem%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CId%3EId%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CName%3EName%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CDescription%3EDescription%3C%2FDescription%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3CType%3EType%3C%2FType%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FContainerItem%3E';

var xml = qs.parse(str);
// data.text
```

The parsed query string is now in an object, so you can now pass `data.text` to your XML parser:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
  // parsed XML is in result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are consuming a Web Service, which uses XML for information exchange.
Now, to do this in Node, using Express, we need a library called "request", this library although discontinued, is useful for this functionality. Also we need "xml2js", to parse the result.

```
import {request, response} from 'express';
import http_request from 'request';
import xml2js from 'xml2js';
```

I put it that way `http_request` so as not to confuse it with the other `request` variable that corresponds to express.

In my case, I use a Web Service for authentication, it's paramaters are user and password and it's returns true or false.

Before to make a try, be sure if works for example in Postman o SoapUI, in my case I use Postman for this, have at hand that request, because it's necesary some headers and the body, obviusly.

In the controller that allows your request, must look like this:

```
export const postAutenticacionAD = async ( req = request, res = response) => {
const {usuario, password} = req.body;
let belongAD = false;
// This is Postman body, that works the Web Service, I just copy all the request
const xml = 
`
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="your-xml-schema" xmlns:xsd="your-xml-schema-again" xmlns:soap="another-schema">
<soap:Body>
<Autenticacion xmlns="other-uri">
    <user>${user}</user>
    <password>${password}</password>
</Autenticacion>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
`;
// Here it's de request instance
http_request({
    // Url for your web service
    url:`http://your-web-server.com/WSApp-cool/Service.asmx`,
    // It's necesary to be post request
    method: 'POST',
    // The body upside
    body: xml,
    // Header from postman, just this for arguments
    headers: {
    'Content-Type':'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Content-Length':xml.length,
    'SOAPAction':"http://tempuri.org/Autenticacion"
    }
}, (error, response, body)=>{
    // This is the 1st callback
    if(error){
        // If some bad happends, just a return for stop all
        console.log(`Error: `,error);
        return res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'Hubo un error en la peticion al AD'
        })
    }
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
        // The request was good, here is the parser from xml to json
        const parser = new xml2js.Parser({
            explicitArray: false,
            trim: true,
        });
        parser.parseString(body, (err, result)=>{
            // Another callback, this time is in the parser
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: `Ha ocurrido un error en el proceso`,
                    err
                })
            }
            // At this point we have our response, now we extract it
            belongAD = result['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['AutenticacionResponse']['AutenticacionResult'];
        });
        // Add more activities, like find in Database
        res.json({
            //Here is the response in json
            msg: 'Resultado de la peticion',
            belongAD
        })
    }
    
})
```

}